# Is it okay to call a person who has "absent" on their outlook?

Tags: colleagues

If I look into my supervisors outlook, she has appointments all throughout the day and then "absent" directly afterwards. What does "absent" mean? Does it mean the person is not at the office or that she is not available at all? Would it be okay to call her when "absent" is set in her outlook?

Comment: What's your understanding of the meaning of 'absent' ?

Comment: Do you normally look into other peoples Outlook Calendar before calling them?

Comment: Do you equate "absent" to "available to you"?

Comment: Since your company uses Outlook, I’m assuming you also have a messaging service like Teams. I would try sending her a quick message, “Hey boss, I have a few questions about ____. Do you have a few minutes to jump on a call?”

Comment: The fact that she has meetings scheduled throughout the day is a good indication that you should probably be scheduling meetings as well. (As opposed to just calling when there’s an open spot on the calendar.)

Comment: Will you call on a work phone? A mobile?

Answer (score 9):

**No**, definitely not.

"Absent" covers a variety of different situations from "holiday" to "medical appointment" to "Physically present but so don't want to be bothered that you should treat it as if I'm not here", in pretty much any of those they aren't going to welcome calls.

Sure you *could* try and reach out - but that's only going to paint you as someone who doesn't understand what the word means or as someone who believes that it doesn't apply to them. Best case scenario they're going to think you've not seen it.

If the motivation behind the call is an unexpected emergency and you *need* their input that's one thing, but otherwise treat it exactly like you would if the person was uncontactable.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your description, your supervisor is rather busy.

Some of my colleagues and myself have taken the approach of creating blockers in our calendars to make it apparent, that we like to take a lunch break or will leave the office / the desk at a certain time. That is especially needed in times of more mobile work / homeoffice where professional and personal live tend to mix. And it is sometimes the only way to dissuade people to create more meetings for you.

That being said, I would not mind it, if somebody called me during these times.
However, I would take the liberty of not answering, if I already stopped working.

An alternate approach would be to contact your supervisor via mail or instant messenger and ask for a short talk when you need her.
That would also be a possibility of adressing the etiquette of reaching out to her in her absent times.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that regardless of her status in outlook, you should probably send a direct message asking if the person is available before calling them, or even propose a meeting and see if the person accepts.

Regarding the meaning of "absent" in Outlook, it could mean that the person wants to keep these time slots for their own work and dont want people to propose meetings at these hours. It could also mean that the person is genuinely busy at these hours for several reasons, related to work or not.

Comment: So you would send a message even if they had the status “available”?

Comment: @Solar In our company we stopped using office land lines or VoIP connectors after COVID emerged. So calling means Zooming. I never ZOOM anybody (and especially my manager) without asking for permission via IM first.

Comment: @SolarMike Does not harm. I do that always and I'd appreciate if others also do this. Reason? Many. Example: I may want a moment to plug in my headset before I take the call, I may be occupied in another meeting in a different platform than the official IM channel which shows my status, ete etc.

Comment: @SouravGhosh so showing "available" on the status is just a waste of time... based on your analysis. Why don't you keep your status up to date? or is it a case of "forgetting".

Comment: @SolarMike not really. At times, we still ask for permission before entering even if the door is open. Consider it as more of a courtesy.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it okay to call a person who has "absent" on their outlook?*

**Short answer:** NO.

They did set that status for a reason, respect that. Do not try to involve / engage them when they meant to be absent / away from work.

However, in expectational scenarios, where you'd *absolutely* need their immediate intervention into something, you can do couple of things based on the scenario:

#### Something unplanned comes up

1. Try reaching the person over a phone call (if you have their number). No matter how urgent it is, if they answer the call, do not forget to mention that this is a work related call and ask whether they are okay to talk about it for a short while. If the answer if affirmative, then you can talk.
2. Try leaving an instant message and expect that they see that and reply. Do not just say "hi"/"hello" in the IM, write a one-liner which covers the topic and mentions the urgency. Request them to reach out to you, or ask whether you can dial them up.

#### Something that can be planned ahead but falls outside work time

1. Send a meeting request well ahead of time, mentioning the need to have the discussion outside the available hours. Wait for acceptance.
2. Send a reminder / request (in-person, over IM) while you still have time, so that they can accommodate you for the discussion.

Comment: Reason behind disagreement? How can this answer be improved?